# Any competitors to db4o on compact framework?

Tags: compact-framework, db4o

We've been trying db4o for persisting objects on the compact framework. It works very well from our tests so far. However, it appears they are on the expensive side for small startups with minimal units needed.

Does anyone know of any similar object databases for the compact framework? How about a open source one that is free for commercial use? :)

Thank you.

EDIT: We're really looking for an object database. We don't want to create our own persistence framework at this point and would prefer being able to just save/retrieve the actual object trees.

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean, a true open source one? db4o is available under the GPLv2 version, which is pretty much «true open source». The fact that you don't want to comply to the GPL is another thing, but db4o is open source.

Comment: Good point. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 2):

How about [SQL Server CE](http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/compact.aspx), [VistaDB](http://www.vistadb.net) or [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org)?

Comment: We were using SQL CE but are looking for the simplicity of an OBDMS.

Comment: tbh simplicity ain't something you really want on embedded. FAST is what you'll end up wanting, well if your project is anything approaching large. db4o is good for speed in some scenarios (it seriously rocks on a simple select) but overall I think SqlLite wins.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it and I'm not sure what the commercial licensing is like, but this might be worth looking at:

[Perst - An open source, object-oriented embedded database](http://www.mcobject.com/perst_features_benefits)

Answer (score 1):

A free for commercial use .NET Object database is Eloquera ( http://www.eloquera.com ).

"Eloquera is a native .NET object database.

- Save the data with a single line of code
- 1TB+ max database size
- List item
- SQL and LINQ queries
- Simultaneous user access
- Security settings
- Has genuine C/S architecture, has desktop mode available
- Supports in-memory database for the fast data processing
  and many more
- it is completely FREE for commercial use."

Comment: I don't believe Eloquera works with the Compact Framework. It's not documented on their website.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're using Java:

Berkeley DB look like it could be right up your alley

[link text](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/berkeley-db/je/index.html)

Commercial, but IIRC license costs aren't very high.

[link text](http://www.progress.com/objectstore/pse_pro/index.ssp)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. We're using .Net...but something with low initial license costs would be nice. We don't mind paying for good software, it's just hard to justify large initial outlays for software for pilot projects.